# how to remove the xml elements with the help of the xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

How to remove the child elements,nodes and parent elements in the xml with the help of xsl.

here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Checkpax xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
    <customerLevel>
        <surname>MUKHERJEE</surname>
        <type>A</type>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <otherPaxDetails>
            <givenName>JOY</givenName>
            <title>MR</title>
            <age>11</age>
        </otherPaxDetails>
        <otherPaxDetails>
            <title>MR</title>
        </otherPaxDetails>
        <staffDetails>
            <staffInfo/>
            <staffCategoryInfo>
                <attributeDetails>
                    <attributeType>NA</attributeType>
                </attributeDetails>
            </staffCategoryInfo>
        </staffDetails>
        <productLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>abc</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
        </productLevel>
        <CustomerLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>cde</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
        </CustomerLevel>
    </customerLevel>
</Checkpax>
```

The expected output xml :

```
<Checkpax xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
    <paxDetails>
        <surname>MUKHERJEE</surname>
        <gender>M</gender>
    </paxDetails>
    <otherPaxDetails>
        <title>MR</title>
        <age>11</age>
    </otherPaxDetails>
    <otherPaxDetails>
        <title>MR</title>
    </otherPaxDetails>
    <staffDetails>
        <staffCategoryInfo>
            <attributeDetails>
                <attributeType>NA</attributeType>
            </attributeDetails>
        </staffCategoryInfo>
    </staffDetails>
    <legLevelIndicator>
        <statusDetails>
            <indicator>abc</indicator>
        </statusDetails>
    </legLevelIndicator>
    <CustomerLevel>
        <legLevel>
            <legLevelIndicator>
                <indicator>cde</indicator>
                <action>1</action>
            </legLevelIndicator>
        </legLevel>
    </CustomerLevel>
</Checkpax>
```

The XSL i tried from my end :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test"
    xmlns:ns0="http://xml.api.com/test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Apply all child nodes; don't copy the element itself -->
  <xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel| ns0:customerDetails| ns0:paxDetails">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Kindly suggest the xsl stylesheet for get the expected xml output.i dont know the remianing things how to remove the element.also this will help lot for many people who are looking for the element removal in xml with xsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, your second template needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:productLevel | ns0:legLevel">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will remove the `productLevel` and `legLevel` wrappers, and elevate `legLevelIndicator` to be a sibling of `staffDetails`.

---

> give me some suggestions how to remove the `<age>11</age>` tag under
>   the otherPaxDetails

Add an *empty* template matching `age`:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:age"/>
```

If you may have other elements with the same name, then narrow down the match pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:otherPaxDetails/ns0:age"/>
```

Comment: give me some suggestions how to remove the <age>11</age> tag under the otherPaxDetails element.@michael.hor257k

Comment: yes this is useful.working for me.sure i will mark it.@michael.hor257k